# window is leaked while hiding a custom dialog

Tags: android

Im using the following code to create a custom dialog.

```
private void alertLoginSuccess() {
        customDialog.loadigText.setText("Login Successful...");
        Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
                .load(R.drawable.tick)
                .into(customDialog.loadigIcon);
        final Handler handler  = new Handler();
        final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (customDialog.isShowing()) {
                    customDialog.hide();
                }
                moveToDashboard(session_token);
            }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
    }
```

When the user has logged in successfully, the login successful dialog will appear and then they will be moved towards the dashboard.

But im getting the following error,

> android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.know.LoginActivity has leaked
>   window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{41ef86e0
>   G.E..... R.....I. 0,0-169,59} that was originally added here
>                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.(ViewRootImpl.java:388)
>                                                                           at
>   android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:248)
>                                                                           at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
>                                                                           at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:286)

How can I be able to sort this out?

Comment: customDialog.dismiss()??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
customDialog.hide();
```

with

```
customDialog.dismiss();
```

because hide() cause a leaked window error, while you are moving to other screen.